# Computer Generates a Number, User Guesses Number, No Matter What it is Always Incorrect

Tags: python, function, variables, global-variables, global

I made a simple program where a user guesses a randomly generated computer number. To test if the program is working, I changed the generated computer value to 5. However, when I "guess" 5, I am somehow still incorrect.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code?

I tried messing about with returning variables but I don't understand how the return command works so I was not successful.

````
def computer_roll():
  global comproll
  comproll = random.randint(1,3)
  # comproll = 5
  user_guess()

def user_guess():
  global user
  user = input("Input a number: ")
  guess_evaluation()

def guess_evaluation():

  if user != comproll:
    print("You are incorrect.")
    again = input("Would you like to try again? ")
    if again in("y"):
      user_guess()

    elif again in ("n"):
      print("Thanks for playing.")

  elif user == comproll:
    print("You are correct.")
    again = input("Would you like to play again? ")
    if again in("y"):
      user_guess()

    elif again in ("n"):
      print("Thanks for playing.")

computer_roll() # Start```



# Expected Results: 

# When I enter 5 it should say "You are correct." and then "Would you like to play again?"

# Actual Results:

# When I enter 5 it says "You are incorrect" and then "Would you like to play again?"
````

Comment: It shows `you are correct` in my system, however the input of `y` and `n` returning an error

Comment: use   `user = int(input("Input a number: "))`

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing integer with string which is why it will never be correct.
Try, `user = int(input("Input a number: "))`

On a sidenote, you really shouldn't be using global variables. Learn to use returns especially since you are using functions, otherwise there is no point using functions at all.

Below is a sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def computer_roll():
  return random.randint(4,6)

def user_guess():
  return int(input("Input a number: "))

def guess_evaluation():

  if user_guess() != computer_roll():
    print("You are incorrect.")
  else:
    print("You are correct.")

  again = input("Would you like to play again? ")

  if again in ("n"):
    print("Thanks for playing.")
  else:
    guess_evaluation()

guess_evaluation()
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works, except for the syntax error at the input field:

```py
def guess_evaluation():

  if user != comproll:
    print("You are incorrect.")
    again = input("Would you like to try again? ")
    if again in("y"): # syntax error here, enter space between "in" and "('y')".
      user_guess()

    elif again in ("n"):
      print("Thanks for playing.")
```

Answer (score 0):

user input curently a string  when comproll is a int. You can change this with:

```
user = int(input("Input a number: "))
```